# Creating an array with entries based on their position in the array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create an array that is populated by integers given a formula for their position in the array.

Basically I'm trying to make an `m X n` matrix where the values of the array are determined by a formula based on their `m` and `n` value.

For example.

```
m = 4
n = 3
```

`a^i,j (A sub i,j)` where `a = i*j` would look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 3, 6]
```

so `A(0,0)` would be `0*0 = 0`

`A(3, 2)` would be `3*2 = 6`

Answer (score 4):

A list comprehension can help here:

```
>>> m = 4
>>> n = 3
>>> [[x * y for y in range(n)] for x in range(m) ]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6]]
```

You can also use NumPy and take advantage of broadcasting:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(m).reshape(m, 1) * np.arange(n)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: Yes both of those worked for me. Although I'm trying to avoid using numpy whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fromfunction for this and just wrap that in numpy.matrix.

```py
numpy.matrix(numpy.fromfunction(lambda x, y: x*y, (4,3), dtype=int))
```

Pass in any shape you like, I chose (4,3) to match your example.

Answer (score 1):

That can easily be accomplished by using `indices` from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

ind = np.indices((4, 3))
```

Then

```
ind[0] * ind[1]
```

gives you the desired result:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: That worked, I am trying to avoid numpy when possible. But this works for this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan: Ok, then MikeMueller's answer is probably what you want :)